Eigenvalues of a particular linear transformation
I'm currently preparing for an exam in my advanced linear algebra class, and ran into the following problem. We're using Halmos' text on finite-dimensional vector spaces.
Suppose I have $k$-linear maps $T_1:V_1 \rightarrow V_1$ and $T_2:V_2 \rightarrow V_2$ for a field $k$ and finite-dimensional vector spaces $V_1$ and $V_2$ over $k$, and I consider the $k$-linear map $T_1 \ast T_2:V_1 \otimes_k V_2 \rightarrow V_1 \otimes_k V_2$ such that $(T_1 \ast T_2)(v_1 \otimes v_2) = T_1(v_1)\otimes v_2 + v_1\otimes T_2(v_2)$. How can I show that any eigenvalue of $T_1 \ast T_2$ is just an eigenvalue of $T_1$ plus an eigenvalue of $T_2$?
Thanks in advance!

Hint: if $v_1$ is an eigenvector of $T_1$ with eigenvalue $\lambda_1$ and $v_2$ is an eigenvector of $T_2$ with eigenvalue $\lambda_2$, how might you form an eigenvector of $T_1 * T_2$ with eigenvalue $\lambda_1 + \lambda_2$?

Suppose that $a \otimes b$ is an eigenvector of $T_1 \ast T_2$ with eigenvalue $\lambda$. Then, $(T_1 \ast T_2)(a \otimes b) = \lambda(a \otimes b)$, which implies $T_1(a) \otimes b + a \otimes T_2(b) = \lambda(a \otimes b)$. But, this means $T_1(a) = \lambda_1a$ for some $\lambda_1$, $T_2(b) = \lambda_2b$ for some $\lambda_2$, and $\lambda = \lambda_1 + \lambda_2$.
Is this a good proof?

Yes, it is but why do you think you need to post it? Isn't it obvious?

Assuming wlog that $k$ is algebraically closed, let $(u_{i,j})_{1\le i\le p, 1\le j\le m_i}$ be a basis of $V_1$ for which the matrix of $T_1$ consists of Jordan blocks with eigenvalues $\lambda_1, \cdots, \lambda_p$, so that $$T_1(u_{i,j})=\lambda_iu_{i,j}+\epsilon_{i,j}u_{i,j-1},$$ where $\epsilon_{1,j}=0$, and $\epsilon_{i,j}=1$ whenever $j>1$. Similarily, let $(v_{k,\ell})_{1\le k\le q, 1\le\ell\le n_k}$ be a basis of $V_2$ for which the matrix of $T_2$ consists of Jordan blocks with eigenvalues $\mu_1,\dots,\mu_q$.
Then, the $u_{i,j}\otimes v_{k,\ell}$s form a basis of $V_1\otimes V_2$, and
$$\begin{align}(T_1\ast T_2)(u_{i,j}\otimes v_{k,\ell})&=(\lambda_iu_{i,j}+\epsilon_{i,j}u_{i,j-1})\otimes v_{k,\ell}+u_{i,j}\otimes(\mu_kv_{k,\ell}+\epsilon_{k,\ell}v_{k,\ell-1})\\
&=(\lambda_i+\mu_k)(u_{i,j}\otimes v_{k,\ell})+\epsilon_{i,j}u_{i,j-1}\otimes v_{k,\ell}+\epsilon_{k,\ell}u_{i,j}\otimes v_{k,\ell-1},
\end{align}$$
which proves the claim.
